# Dispaly URI variable instead of URL path

Tags: c#, windows, forms, uri

Var hi ="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask";
URI hello = new Uri(hi);
Output:
When I click "hi" it should direct me to stack overflow
"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask";

Result:
        I want the "hi" variable to hold the value https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask.but When it runs it should show the "hi" variable not the Url path, I'm trying to do these in "URI" in c# can anyone help me in this thanks in advance

Note : < a href = https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"> hi 
just like a hyperlink but want this to be achieved only using URI in c#

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
    string hi =@"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask";
    Uri hello = new Uri(hi);
```